# Error when creating a drop down menu in a form using PHP

Tags: php, forms

Here's my code:

```
echo '<select  name=\"sv_07\">';   
$vars = array(
'Year' => 'Year'
'-2012' => '2012', 
'-2011' => '2011', 
'-2010' => '2010', 
'-2009' => '2009', 
'-2008' => '2008', 
'-2007' => '2007', 
'-2006' => '2006', 
'-2005' => '2005', 
'Pre 2005' => 'Pre 2005', 
);

foreach($vars as $val => $name){
if($_SESSION['sv_07'] == $val){
    echo '<option value="' . substr($val, 0, 1) . '" selected>' . $name . '</option>';
} else {
    echo '<option value="' . substr($val, 0, 1) . '">' . $name . '</option>';
}
}

echo '</select></div>';
```

As you can see I'm trying to use PHP to echo the tags for a form, and then echo one of two sets of HTML - one for if a value matches one previously submitted to the session, and another for all the others.

It doesn't work and I can't find the error however.

I tried to debug it at http://ideone.com and got the error message:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/4seOiK/prog.php on line 16

Line 16:

```
 if($_SESSION['sv_07'] == $val){
```

I've tried some manual debugging and altered the if requirement to something like

if(1>2)

And the error disappears, howevver I can't for the life of me see what is wrong with my syntax

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing Comma after `'Year' => 'Year'`

Comment: >_< My god, thanks that seems to have pretty much fixed it entirely.

Can't believe that small thing can derail everything so hard! :) You answered so fast I can't even accept your answer yet, will surely green tick you when 5 mins is up

Comment: Syntax errors are easily caught when you have the correct line number. Also note that you must bracket your php between <? ?> when using ideone, because I did not catch this at first. I have no idea where the 'line 16' came from, because the error was on line 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can start array keys (even if they are strings) with a dash.

Comment: You can. There are no restrictions on strings for array keys.